# Geostationary Height

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, time

While finding out the geostationary height for a satellite, i got the standard result of about 35000 km. But there always comes a thought in my mind that if we take a radially outward line, place a satellite with appropriate velocity on the radial line, still it will move with earth, and would appear stationary relative to it, and we will have a huge number of geostationary heights. 
I feel somewhere i am wrong, please Help, and feel free to add in any extra info or sources which could help me.

Comment: No, the relevant (simple) formulas show very clearly, that there is only a single geostationary height. If you move the satellite ourward, the gravitational force of the Earth will be smaller, but the velocity required for geostationary orbit would grow. There is only a single match, always.

Comment: What is the "appropriate velocity" to remain geostationary at an altitude of 2m and does this velocity allow a circular orbit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for geosynchronous orbit is that the angular velocity of the satellite and of the planet are the same. That is, $$ \omega_s=\frac{v_s}{r_s}=\frac{v_e}{r_e}=\omega_e$$

If you give it this velocity up higher than geosynchronous orbit, it will not travel in a circle around the earth but rather an ellipse. The earth's gravity at that height is weaker than at geosynchronous orbit, but the force required 
to keep it in a circular orbit is: $$F_c=m\omega^2 r$$

Since a geosynchronous orbit requires $\omega$ to be fixed, this required centripetal force increases with the height of the satellite. Since the actual force $F_g=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ is insufficient, the satellite will initially drift outwards. By conservation of energy, $v$ will decrease, and since $r$ is getting larger, $\omega$ will decrease even more. And thus it is not in a geosynchronous orbit: $\omega$ is not even constant, much less constant and equal to the earth's rotational speed.

Comment: This isn't quite right - the proposed velocities are smaller, not larger, than required for a circular orbit. Thus gravity is stronger, not weaker, and the elliptical orbit will go closer to the surface rather than higher.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It depends what you keep fixed. I was keeping the angular velocity fixed (the condition fpr geosynchronous orbit) as the radius increases. In this case, gravity is weaker because you're higher and the centripetal force required for a circular path is larger.

Comment: This answer may be ok, but it's hard to say.   It is not clearly presented.

Comment: @garyp Hm, I'll clarify it when I get a chance then

Comment: Not absolutely clear..but now atleast i have something to think upon..

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two formulae:

$$v=\omega r$$
$$a={v^2 \over r}$$

The former describes the speed for a certain distance, when the angular speed is set. The latter describes the requirement for the path to be circular. In particular, note the squared $v$.

According to the former expression, keeping $\omega$ constant (necessary for a geostationary satellite) means that increasing the distance will linearly (proportionally) increase the speed as well.

According to the latter expression, increasing the distance will only inversely quadratically increase the speed. Not linearly. (The $a$ will also change with distance, a factor we could add with Newton's law of gravity, but the influence is not that big.)

This means that reaching a new circular orbit (the latter expression) will require the $\omega$ to change in the former expression. If it doesn't change, then the relationship between $r$ and $v$ is linear, and the latter expression is not fulfilled, causing the orbit to not be circular.

Only at a certain height do the two expressions fit at the same time as the $\omega$ equals that of  earth. Only this height gives a geostationary orbit.